# How to keep track of data over various periods of time (Swift) - Counter/Habit Tracking App

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, time

I'm trying to create a simple counter/habit tracking app that allows users to see how many times they've completed a task over a certain amount of time (daily/weekly/monthly/yearly/total).

**My question is: what is the best way to track variables over time such that when the user selects a time period, the variable's value can update to reflect that change?**

A few examples to clarify what I mean:

- A user who initially created a monthly timer to track workouts should be able to switch to a weekly timer and see the data update as needed (there should be fewer in a week than in a month).
- A user who has created a daily counter should see the daily counter reset to 0 at midnight each day, with the previous day's value visible to compare.
- A user who has created a "total" counter should be able to switch to any time period (daily/weekly/monthly/yearly) and see the counter update as needed.

The UI for my app is basically a custom tableview with the counter number, counter name, and the time period over which the counter number is being tracked. A detail view allows users to add to/subtract from the counter's value.

I have been wracking my brain and Google for a long time, so I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each task should have a date. When app needs to query for the average per day/week/month/year you can use a `NSPredicate` to restrict only the results from a given time period.

For instance, here's a predicate that models the last-week scenario that I have written for an app of mine:

```
  func lastWeekPredicate() -> NSPredicate {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let endDate = NSDate()
    let startDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: -7, toDate: endDate, options: nil)
    return NSPredicate(format: "day >= %@ AND day =< %@", argumentArray: [startDate!, endDate!])
  }
```

Let's say you modelled your data with Core Data. Querying with this predicate would give you the results of all the tasks that were completed in the last week. The predicate can be modified to work for days, months, year, or any specified number of days.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! It's a bit overwhelming for me, though, since I'm pretty new to iOS programming, so I was wondering if you could clarify a couple of things. Basically, I am currently storing each counter's data in a variable that is created when a counter is created. How exactly would I implement your above code to restrict the results? Do I run the code as soon as a new counter is created?

Comment: How are you persisting the counter data?

Comment: I've just been storing the data in Int variables. Would it be better to use Core Data?

Comment: My sincerest condolences... you'll be spending a good week or two learning how to persist data :]. From what I gather from your question, this is a long-term tracker that requires the data to be saved so it can be retrieved even after you app is killed, for instance, when you turn your phone off. Storing the data  and persisting the data are two different things.

Core Data is a good way to persist your data, and it has methods that query the data from the data store that accepts `NSPredicate` that will allow you to do what you intend to do.

Comment: Haha thank you for your candor, I guess I'll have to learn how to use Core Data now and then I'll see if I can use your method. If you know any good tutorials, please let me know! I'll accept your answer.

Comment: RayWenderlich.com is the way to go. I learned from there and now I write with them. They have a book dedicated to Core Data. It will be a heavy read for beginners, but it will have all the info you need to get you running. Alternatively there are articles within the site that gives you a general overview of Core Data that will be helpful too.

Comment: Thanks! I've added CoreData to my project but I'm not quite sure how the NSPredicate will work. When you say it restricts the results to a given time period, do you mean that counters started before a certain time (day/week/month) will not show, or do you mean that only the average value of each counter over the past certain time will show? If you don't know exactly what I mean, I can email you some screenshots that may better illustrate it. Thanks again!

Comment: Imagine a collection your data, they all contain the value and the date of when the value was collected. When you fetch the data from your collection of data, `NSPredicates` can be used to filter your search, kind of like "advanced search" in google. Depending on how you set up your predicate, you can return specific results. Creating the predicate I mentioned will give you results that only pertain to the last week of data - much like "results for last 1 week" in google advanced search - or any search engine really.